# Chrome driver throwing error- Loading of unpacked extension is disabled by administrator

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Yesterday my chrome version got updated to 76, I updated my chrome driver for the same- `ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.12`, I am facing the same error msg. I have used `options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);` already, but still getting the same error every time before launching chrome. Please help as it is blocking my batch execution.

With last update of chrome same error was coming but go resolved with :

opts.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);

ChromeOptions opts = new ChromeOptions();

```
        opts.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        opts.addArguments("no-sandbox");
        opts.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        opts.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);

        //opts.addArguments("start-maximized");
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, opts);


        //webdriver = new ChromeDriver(opts);
        webdriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

```
Want to remove this warning pop up so that I can resume execution.
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it solved by using chrome options instead of capabilities as below:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('-disable-extensions')
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Have a look at one `'-'` instead of `'--'` in the argument. When I used `'--disable-extensions'` id didn't work. Maybe some side effect. The code is in python, but java variation could work as well.

Comment: Tried removing one ' - ' , did not work for me. Error is still coming before launching Google chrome